# Как с помощью библиотеки sox поменять частоту аудиофайла

Tags: python

Это мой код. Проблема в том, что для функции нужно два параметра - входной и выходной аудиофайл. Однако мне не нужно ничего менять кроме частоты и количества каналов   transformer.build(filename)

```html
for f in tqdm(wav_dir.rglob("*.wav")):
    filename=str(f)
    transformer = sox.Transformer()
    transformer.convert(samplerate=SAMPLE_RATE, n_channels=CHANNELS)
    try:
        transformer.build(filename)
    except sox.core.SoxError:
        pass
```

Comment: Ну, пишите во временный файл, потом переименовывайте его. Либо можно выход получить в массив и потом этот массив записать в исходный файл. В любом случае нужно какое-то промежуточное звено, нельзя один файл и читать и писать одновременно.

Comment: Это очень не просто, так как поток должен быть переконструирован. Вы вообще смотрели, как устроен контейнер WAV?